# ¿Cómo desbloqueo la librería para poder editar cesium js?

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con `cesium.js`, necesito cambiar las propiedades de `InfoBox`, encontré en la carpeta `source` muy detallado el código de la la sección `InfoBox`.

Cómo puedo editar la librería `Cesium.js` o hacer que lea el `infobox.js` detallado de `source` que si puedo editar o como puedo desbloquear  `cesium` para editarla.